# React Native Showing Text Box onPress?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am a Newbie to ReactNative, what I want is whenever a user clicks on a button user should get a popup box for a comment, but I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

class Check extends Component {
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.pressed = true
}
_callme = () => {
  if(!this.pressed){
    return ( <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._callMe}>
          Show me TextBox
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
    )
  }
  else{
    return (
    <View>
       <TextInput  />
      </View>)
  }
}
showText = () => {
  return (
   <TouchableOpacity on Press={this._callMe}>
     <Text>Show me TextBox</Text>
   </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}
render() { 
  return(
    <View>
      {this.pressed ? this._callMe : this.showText}
    </View>
  )
}
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Check', () => Check);
```

I am Newbie into the ReactNative, what I want is when ever a user clicks on a button user should get a popup box for comment, but I don't know where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to render the returned value, you need to call the function with `()`

```
{this.pressed ? this._callMe() : this.showText()}
```

Also `showText` function return component `<TouchableOpacity on Press={this._callMe}>` has a space between `on Press` change to `onPress`.